# Client Server communication and underlying TCP states

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, client-server, serversocket

I run the following Client-Server code on a linux box

```
Server Code
    public class MyServer {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(6868, 5);
                while (true) {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

Client Code
    public class MyClient {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
            Socket[] clients = new Socket[8];
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                clients[i] = new Socket("175.27.3.4", 6868);
                System.out.printf("Client %2d: " + clients[i] + "%n", i);
                //clients[i].close();
            }
            for (int i = 6; i < 10; i++) {
                clients[i] = new Socket("175.27.3.4", 6868);
                System.out.printf("Client %2d: " + clients[i] + "%n", i);
                //clients[i].close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Note-

1. I have not "ACCEPTED" the client request to test the ServerSocket
   backlog argument.
2. The two loops in the client code are deliberate to help debug the
   code.
3. The Server box is a Cent OS
4. The Client box is Cent OS (different physical server)
5. The client sockets are NOT closed deliberately.

After executing the Server code and later Client code I observe the following

1. On the server using netstat, I see 6 connections in ESTABLISHED
   state
2. On the server using netstat, I see 4 connections in SYN_RECV
   state(backlog queue full)
3. On the client machine, I see all 10 connections in ESTABLISHED
   state- Is this normal?
4. In the wireshark on the server side (tcpdump) for the first 6
   connections, I see a proper 3 way handshake for connection
   establishment (SYN, SYN-ACK, ACK)
5. For the next 4 connections , in the wireshark on the server side, I
   see (SYN [sometimes multiple], SYN-ACK, ACK, then many Duplicate
       SYN-ACKS)

Question -

1. Are all the above observations normal?
2. Are the observations system dependent (OS) ?

Bigger Picture
 Please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28720857/tcp-connections-dropping) OR [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/675523/tcp-connections-drop-off-after-initial-build-up) for detailed explanation

1. I am trying to simulate the production issue on a smaller scale with
   the above code
2. In the production code (which I did not write but I maintain it) the
   server socket has a backlog argument as 100.
3. I suspect the backlog queue is full and hence the newer connections
   are dropped.
4. I see plenty of SYN requests but not many SYN-ACKS in the production
   wireshark which is a hour long. Does it ring a bell and can we draw
   parallel with the toy code above?

Comment: This can't be the real code. The client would throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` and all the connections would close when it exits. What you see on the production server corresponds to filling the backlog queue. When it fills there should be no more SYN-ACKs. What you see on the test client doesn't agree with what you see on the test server, so I suspect your observations or test methodology are wrong somewhere.

Comment: @EJP Agreed, the test client will throw exception. Will fix that. However, if I infer your response, you are saying what I see on production is what I should also see on the test code. The production issue of no SYN-ACK's is caused by the exhaustion of backlog queue? If that is true, at some point the system should stabilize because on production the client keeps retrying, but it never happens.

Comment: Then you have a socket leak at the server.